# javascript best way to split an array into two by delimiter

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, split, delimiter

I have an array in javascript:

```
a=["jhgkhjgk3j_jhgkjhgk","8797823_0120120", "aaaaa_bbb"]
```

I want to get

```
b=["jhgkhjgk3j","8797823", "aaaaa"]
```

and

```
c=["jhgkjhgk","0120120", "bbb"].
```

because of `"_"` delimiter.

Are there any way to get that done without using `for` loop statement?

Comment: What do you have against a `for` statement?

Comment: I assume the last array should be `c`, not `b` again?

Comment: @talemyn  Thank you for poitning that. Typo fixed.

Comment: @cookie monster for statement means for-loop statement. Thank you.

Comment: @Haradzieniec: Sure. What else would it mean? Anyway, a loop of some sort will be needed at some level, but if for some reason you don't want to specifically use a `for` loop, then you can use `Array.prototype.reduce` easily enough.

Comment: @Haradzieniec When you use things like split or join and similar constructs in javascript, they are just abstractions of the underlying for loop that actually gets the work done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just for fun, here's an ECMAScript 6 solution.

```
let [b, c] = a.reduce(function(res, s, i) {
    [res[0][i], res[1][i]] = s.split("_");
    return res;
}, [[],[]]);
```

Will work in Firefox today, and in other browsers in the hopefully not too distant future.

Comment: Not work in Chrome, like scheme style.

Comment: @Tim: Certainly not. ECMAScript 6 hasn't even been released yet. It'll work in Firefox today.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this ES5:

```
 var a=["jhgkhjgk3j_jhgkjhgk","8797823_0120120", "aaaaa_bbb"];

    var items = a.reduce(function(a,b){
        a[0].push(b.split('_')[0]);
        a[1].push(b.split('_')[1]);
        return a;
    },[[],[]]);

    console.log(items);
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a version that should work in Chrome. It also uses `reduce`:

```
var result = a.reduce(function(result, current, i) {
    var parts = current.split(/_/);
    result[0].push(parts[0]);
    result[1].push(parts[1]);

    return result;
}, [[], []]);

var b = result[0];
var c = result[1];
```

Comment: Curse your faster typing skills!   :D

Answer (score 1):

```
var a= ["jhgkhjgk3j_jhgkjhgk","8797823_0120120", "aaaaa_bbb"],
    b = [],
    c = [];

a.forEach(function (value, key) {
    a[key] = value.split('_');
    b.push(a[key][0]);
    c.push(a[key][1]);
});
```